# What uses and fills up ~/.cache/kioexec/krun/?

Tags: kde, cache

I've just noticed some files there that were created a long time ago, they look like copies of my files already present on filesystem elsewhere. What process or processes use this folder and for what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be any KDE based app that need file access, either local or remote.

> ## KIO
>
> Network transparent access to files and data
>
> ### Introduction
>
> This framework implements almost all the file management functions you
> will ever need. In fact, the KDE file manager (Dolphin) and the KDE
> file dialog also uses this to provide its network-enabled file
> management.
>
> It supports accessing files locally as well as via HTTP and FTP out of
> the box and can be extended by plugins to support other protocols as
> well. There is a variety of plugins available, e.g. to support access
> via SSH.
>
> The framework can also be used to bridge a native protocol to a
> file-based interface. This makes the data accessible in all
> applications using the KDE file dialog or any other KIO enabled
> infrastructure.

Source: [Kio git - README](https://invent.kde.org/frameworks/kio)

Check this function here: src/kioexec/main.cpp

Comment: Thank you, didn't have time to research it myself at the time. Filed a bug report: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=413885

Comment: @int_ua, Cleaning them automatically may not be a good option, there is a risk of loosing changes that were not synchronized. If the app or kio detect the crash or residue files, may be better offering the user to recover or dismiss them. Quiet old, code could be changed.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's exactly the thing I'm trying to avoid, it's only the last resort solution. Although I meant `@reboot` so I don't think it would have interfered.