# Kubuntu 18: Dolphin as FTP

Tags: kubuntu, ftp

When editing code online, I use Dolphin for FTP. I can double-click and the file opens in my editor, no problem. When I save in the editor, it uploads the changes. It's ideal.

Right now, the double-clicked file just comes down to a random temp location, and since I have many files that are similarly named, it gets confusing in a hurry. Is it possible to control the location where the file is downloaded when operating in that way?

Comment: Seems hard-codes, related to https://askubuntu.com/q/1186697/26246

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been unable to find a way to get Dolphin to do this. HOWEVER, PCManFM creates a temp path that mirrors the FTP path and fits the bill very well.